# How can I add another property to the json acquired from fetch?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have the following code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    listAccountsWorker()
        .then(res => {
            for (account of res) {
                // Account is not defined
                account.isSelected = false;
            }
            setAccounts(accounts)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            if (error.status === 401) {
                history.push('/login');
            }
        });
}, []);
```

I want to add a new property to the object in the array `isSelected` however I am getting the error `'account' is not defined`. Worker uses `JS` fetch and returns the result in a promise the contents of `res` is an array of objects e.g. `[{ label: 'hello', ...}, { label: 'bye', ...}]`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
    listAccountsWorker()
        .then(res => {
            // defined `account`
            for (const account of res) {
                account.isSelected = false;
            }
            setAccounts(accounts)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            if (error.status === 401) {
                history.push('/login');
            }
        });
}, []);
```